# What's the easiest way to call a function every 5 seconds in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, timer

JQuery, how to call a function every 5 seconds.

I'm looking for a way to automate the changing of images in a slideshow.

I'd rather not install any other 3rd party plugins if possible.

Comment: +1 for "I'd rather not install any 3rd party plugins if possible."

Comment: @nickf: Because it's humorous as jQuery is already 3rd-party? (But not really, because I'm sure he's using jQuery for other stuff already)

Comment: @Mark, hehe no I wasn't being sarcastic, it's just that I see a lot of people jump straight to plugins even though their problem could be solved with a couple of lines of plain javascript.

Comment: A couple of lines of quirky hacks and you never know in which browsers it will work.

Comment: Note that for those looking to use this technique in combination with an AJAX request - ***DON'T DO IT THIS WAY***. Having every user on your page call your server every N seconds is equivalent of DDOSing yourself. If you need to keep the server and UI in sync, use WebSockets instead.

Comment: Just to expand on the comment of @RoryMcCrossan, if you have to use intervals (because technical reasons maybe), make your program so that a connection failure increases the delay between reconnect attempts, instead of decreasing like some [netgear routers](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~plonka/netgear-sntp/) did in the past

Answer (score 1129, accepted):

You don't need jquery for this, in plain javascript, the following will work:

```
var intervalId = window.setInterval(function(){
  // call your function here
}, 5000);
```

To stop the loop you can use:

```
clearInterval(intervalId)
```

Comment: Who says I can't refresh every 2 seconds :D

Comment: @Alucard The asker didn't specify the need for it to ever stop, so I say no need.

Comment: @andrewb nevertheless, it is useful for others who find this question and DO need clearInterval().

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_clearinterval.asp

Comment: You wrote a function more parsimonious than w3schools - way to go!

Answer (score 140):

you could register an interval on the page using setInterval, ie:

```
setInterval(function(){ 
    //code goes here that will be run every 5 seconds.    
}, 5000);
```

Comment: yeah i fixed it, trying to type too fast, knew it would be answered quickly :)

Comment: Your opening suggestion still references setTimeout :)

Comment: well, thanks :) man it's late. need to stop trying to answer questions when tired.

Comment: You could always call `setTimeout` again from within the function....that's the way I used to do it >.< I guess it can't be an anonymous function then. Unless there's some sort of call_self() function I'm unaware of.

Comment: @Mark Yup, that's how I do it when timing is not very critical, but a job needs to execute periodically.

Comment: For those now in the world of ES6, this should be useful: setInterval(() => { alert("Meow i'm a cat"); }, 1000);

Answer (score 63):

A good example where to subscribe a setInterval(), and use a clearInterval() to stop the forever loop:

```
function everyTime() {
    console.log('each 1 second...');
}

var myInterval = setInterval(everyTime, 1000);
```

call this line to stop the loop:

```
 clearInterval(myInterval);
```

Answer (score 50):

Just a little tip for the first answer. If your function is already defined, reference the function but don't call it!!! So don't put any parentheses after the function name. Just like:

```
my_function(){};
setInterval(my_function,10000);
```

Comment: If you do not call it once, the first call will be in 10000ms. If you want one right away, you can still call it normally once.

Comment: This answer has saved me a LOT of time; I would've been wondering why my function wasn't being called for ages.  Lucky I stumbled across this answer; +1

Answer (score 39):

The functions mentioned above execute no matter if it has completed in previous invocation or not, this one runs after every x seconds once the execution is complete

```
// IIFE
(function runForever(){
  // Do something here
  setTimeout(runForever, 5000)
})()

// Regular function with arguments
function someFunction(file, directory){
  // Do something here
  setTimeout(someFunction, 5000, file, directory)
  // YES, setTimeout passes any extra args to
  // function being called
}
```

Answer (score 14):

Both `setInterval` and `setTimeout` can work for you (<strike>as @Doug Neiner and @John Boker wrote</strike> both now point to `setInterval`).
See [here](http://www.elated.com/articles/javascript-timers-with-settimeout-and-setinterval/) for some more explanation about both to see which suits you most and how to stop each of them.

Answer (score 7):

you can use window.setInterval and time must to be define in miliseconds, in below case the function will call after every single second (1000 miliseconds)

```
<script>
  var time = 3670;
window.setInterval(function(){

  // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
    var h = Math.floor(time / 3600);
    var m = Math.floor(time % 3600 / 60);
    var s = Math.floor(time % 3600 % 60);

  // Display the result in the element with id="demo"
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =  h + "h "
  + m + "m " + s + "s ";

  // If the count down is finished, write some text 
  if (time < 0) {
    clearInterval(x);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
  }

  time--;
}, 1000);


</script>
```