# Call a Javascript function every 5 seconds continuously

Tags: javascript, dom-events

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Calling a function every 60 seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3138756/jquery-repeat-function-every-60-seconds)

I want to Call a Javascript function every 5 seconds continuously. 
I have seen the setTimeOut event. Will it be working fine if I want it continuously?

Comment: duplicates http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2170923/whats-the-easiest-way-to-call-a-function-every-5-seconds-in-jquery

Answer (score 312):

You can use [`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setInterval), the arguments are the same.

```
const interval = setInterval(function() {
   // method to be executed;
 }, 5000);

clearInterval(interval); // thanks @Luca D'Amico
```

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2003/11/01/53329.aspx

Comment: @Anantha: FYI, The code you had before your latest edit (after my edit) (`setInterval(methodName,5000)`), did not use `eval`. `eval` is only used in `setInterval`/`setTimeout` if the first parameter is passed as a string.

Comment: As a side note: if you want to stop your Interval, you should call `clearInterval()` passing your Interval ID as a parameter.

Comment: slightly improved:

function anyActivity(){
 //do something.
}

const interval = setInterval(anyActivity, 5000);
   
window.onbeforeunload = function(){
 clearInterval(interval);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
 anyActivity();
});

Answer (score 142):

Do a "recursive" `setTimeout` of your function, and it will keep being executed every amount of time defined:

```
function yourFunction(){
    // do whatever you like here

    setTimeout(yourFunction, 5000);
}

yourFunction();
```

Comment: I'm curious, won't this cause a memory leak eventually?

Comment: @KarlMorrison No, using `setInterval` can cause a memory leak. By using `setTimeout` you ensure that the next function call won't get triggered **until** the previous function call has finished.

Comment: How do we break out of this?

Comment: @SarasArya Easily, you can have a variable outside the scope of the function which holds a state. Then, before setting the timeout inside the function again, you do an IF check. So, according to the logic you need, you set the timeout or not as needed.

Comment: @Shef Thanks... Geez that was easy. :P

Comment: I had to add `() =>` as the function was executing in a loop. `setTimeout(() => yourFunction, 5000);`

Comment: @Defozo That doesn't seem right. Were you using `yourFunction()` instead, maybe?

Answer (score 59):

As [best coding practices](https://bonsaiden.github.io/JavaScript-Garden/#other.timeouts) suggests, use `setTimeout` instead of `setInterval`.

```
function foo() {

    // your function code here

    setTimeout(foo, 5000);
}

foo();
```

Please note that this is NOT a recursive function. The function is not calling itself before it ends, it's calling a `setTimeout` function that will be later call the same function again.

Comment: This also executes the code immediately the first time, while setInterval waits first.

Comment: How do I make this function stop? Also, I'm getting a stack overflow.

Comment: setTimeout returns a timeoutID you can then pass to clearTimeout to stop it for good. You won't get a stack overflow if you follow the example of the answer. You are likely calling the function recursively, instead of letting the setTimeout method call it

Comment: Edit queue is full, just wanted to say that this will call the function every **5 minutes**, not **5 seconds**.

Comment: @ThatBirdThatLearnedToCode setTimeout second argument is in milliseconds. 1000 ms is 1 second, so 5000 is 5 seconds. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout

Comment: @Jose Faeti lol I am an idiot, I forgot how to read milliseconds (I knew it was milliseconds)

Answer (score 28):

For repeating an action in the future, there is the built in [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval)  function that you can use instead of `setTimeout`.
It has a similar signature, so the  transition from one to another is simple:

```
setInterval(function() {
    // do stuff
}, duration);
```

Answer (score 6):

**Good working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/MrTest/t4NXD/62/)**

```js
/*!  MenuAutoActive
---------------------------------------------*/
(function($) {

    $.fn.NoticeBoard = function() {


        // Set a timeout
        var timeOut = setTimeout(nextNotice, 5000);

        // pause on hover
        $('.noticeboard').hover(

        function() {
            clearTimeout(timeOut);
        }, function() {
            timeOut = setTimeout(nextNotice, 5000);
        });

        // Next notice function called on timeout or click
        //set a flag that use to be an oberver to listen when the fadeIn done
        var flag = true;
        function nextNotice(event) {
            if(!flag){
                return false;
            }
            clearTimeout(timeOut);
            
            flag = false;
            timeOut = setTimeout(nextNotice, 5000);

            if ($('.noticeboard span:visible').is('.noticeboard span:last-child')) {
                $('.noticeboard span:visible').fadeOut(300);
                $('.noticeboard span:first-child').fadeIn("slow",function(){
                    flag = true;
                });
            }
            else {
                $('.noticeboard span:visible').fadeOut(300).next().fadeIn("slow",function(){
                    flag = true;
                });
            }
            return false;
        }

        $('#notice-next').click(nextNotice);
        $('#notice-prev').click(function(event) {
            
            if(!flag){
                return false;
            }
            clearTimeout(timeOut);
            
            flag = false;
            timeOut = setTimeout(nextNotice, 5000);


            if ($('.noticeboard span:visible').is('.noticeboard span:first-child')) {
                $('.noticeboard span:visible').fadeOut(300);
                $('.noticeboard span:last-child').fadeIn("slow",function(){
                    flag = true;
                });
            }
            else {
                 $('.noticeboard span:visible').fadeOut(300).prev().fadeIn("slow",function(){
                    flag = true;
                });
            }
            return false;

        });

    };

/*!  
---------------------------------------------*/

})(jQuery);

/*!  OnLoad
---------------------------------------------*/
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.noticeboard span').hide();
    $('.noticeboard span:first').show();
    $('.noticeboard').NoticeBoard();

});
```

```css
/* NOTICE BOARD */
.noticeboard { position: relative; min-height: 150px;}
.noticeboard span { display: none; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px;}
.noticeboard strong { padding-right: 30px; display: block;}
#notice-next { position: absolute; top: 50px; right: 10px; z-index: 100;}
#notice-prev { position: absolute; top: 50px; right: 30px; z-index: 100;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="action-box">
    <!-- NOTICEBOARD NAV -->
    <a href="#" id="notice-prev">«</a>
    <a href="#" id="notice-next">»</a>
    <!-- /NOTICEBOARD NAV -->
    
    <span class="ge"></span>
    <div class="noticeboard" style="height: 145px;">
        
        <span style="display: block;"><strong>Boy, 14, found stabbed to death</strong><a href="http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-england-14570107">A 14-year-old boy has been found stabbed to death in a park in north London.</a></span><span style="display: block;"><strong>A-level passes rise for 29th year</strong><a href="http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/education-14558490">Hundreds of thousands of teenagers are getting their A-level results amid an intense battle for university places ahead of tuition fee rises.</a></span><span style="display: none;"><strong>UK: Matter of time for Gaddafi</strong><a href="http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-politics-14625484">Deputy Prime Minister Nick Clegg has said it is "only a matter of time" before Col Muammar Gaddafi is defeated.</a></span>                </div>
</div>
```

Plus:

- has nice `fade in / fade out` animation
- will pause on `:hover`
- will prevent running multiple actions (finish run animation before starting second)
- will prevent going broken when in the tab ( browser stops scripts in the tabs)

Tested and working!

Comment: thanks man its superb work great.... great job

Comment: #Iladarsda is there any way to stop auto fade and only fade on next click or prev click

Comment: @MichaelM. Most content has some value, thus it is better to try to save it before you try to destroy it. It was not that hard to extract the code from JSFiddle and insert it into the answer via a Stack snippet.