# how to execute next after few seconds for a carousel in angular?

Tags: angular, carousel, angular2-template

I am using [ng2-carouselamos](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-carouselamos) for a carousel to display with below code successfully.

```
<div
    ng2-carouselamos
    class="slides-wrapper"
    [items]="items"
    [width]="1200"
    [$prev]="prev"
    [$next]="next"
    [$item]="item">
  </div>

  <ng-template #prev>
    <img src="assets/images/left_arrow.png" id="left" />
  </ng-template>
  <ng-template #next>
    <img src="assets/images/right_arrow.png" id="right" />
  </ng-template>
  <ng-template #item let-item let-i="index">
    <div class="items">
      <img src="{{ item.name }}">
    </div>
  </ng-template>
```

and ts as below:

```
this.items = [
      { name: 'assets/images/professional_website.jpg' },
      { name: 'assets/images/nature_1200_800.jpg' },
      { name: 'assets/images/nature.jpg' },
      { name: 'assets/images/nature.jpg' },
      { name: 'assets/images/nature.jpg' }, ]
```

how to call [$next]="next" from within ts to automatically executes it after 5 sec?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source of your problem is to call a function (the next call) every 5 seconds.

So as noted in [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7188145/call-a-javascript-function-every-5-seconds-continuously):

You can use setInterval(), the arguments are the same.

```
setInterval(function() {
  // method to be executed;
}, 5000);
```

And thus, in your case, on ngInit you can have this type of code:

```
// we need to access programmatically the scroll function since it isn't exposed 
// by the library
@ViewChild(Ng2Carouselamos)
ng2Carouselamos : Ng2Carouselamos;

setInterval(function() {
  ng2Carouselamos.scroll(true,items);
}, 5000);
```

However, since the library you are using isn't maintained any more and lacks simple features (such as autoscroll) I'd suggest opting for a more modern component library (like [prime-ng](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/carousel) which supports this with continuous=true ) or [Ngu-Carousel](https://github.com/sheikalthaf/ngu-carousel)