# How to trigger click event of button after period of time in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I tried to trigger click event of button after 3 mins using below javascript code

```
setTimeout(function(){$(‘._my_save_button’).trigger(‘click’)},180000);
```

Above code throws error when we run in chrome console

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
```

Comment: `setTimeout(function(){$('_my_save_button').trigger('click')},180000);` .............. `‘_my_save_button’` => `'_my_save_button'`

Comment: Your single quotes are 'weird'. Try using normal single (or double) quotes: `'` or `"`. Also, your `_my_save_button` is really nothing. If it's the id of the button, you should add the prefix `#` to that.

Comment: does your button have the class or id `_my_save_button`? if it is the class, prepend it with a `.`, if id, prepend with `#`.

Comment: Looks like dublicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/7188145/8623919

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We need to fix the quotes around your identifier.

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $('._my_save_button').trigger('click');
}, 3000);
```

Comment: I suggest you to always use double quotes. I have seen many systems/PC with a different single quote.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are only missing the right css selector.

should be `"#_my_save_button"` in case of `id="_my_save_button"`
or `"._my_save_button"` in case of `class="_my_save_button"`:

```
setTimeout(function(){$("#_my_save_button").trigger("click")},180000);
```