# Make a javascript method execute every n milliseconds

Tags: javascript, object

I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7188145/call-a-javascript-function-every-5-seconds-continuously) post about executing a function every n seconds, but I am working with classes and want to execute the method every n seconds.

I have 2 objects, and each one will have a method that will execute every n seconds.

```
class MyClass {
  constructor() {
    //stuff
  }
  myMethod() {
    //other stuff to execute every n seconds
  }
}

var obj1 = new MyClass()
, obj2 = new MyClass();
```

How would I go about doing this?

EDIT: Sorry for the confusion, but i wanted to be able to use the `this` keyword in the interval

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp

Comment: How did the answers from the question you linked not help you? Have you tried using `setTimeout` or `setInterval`? Please post the code of that attempt.

Comment: In those posts i cannot use the `this` keyword

Comment: Relevant: [How to access the correct `this` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20279484/218196)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) to call a function every n milliseconds:

```js
class MyClass {
  doSomething() {
    console.log('doSomething() called..')
  }
}

var o = new MyClass();

setInterval(o.doSomething, 1000);
```

Comment: With this i cannot use the `this` keyword

Comment: @Ankizle: https://stackoverflow.com/q/20279484/218196 . Use `setInterval(() => o.doSomething(), 1000)` instead.

Comment: If i use `self` i cannot set new values

Comment: @Ankizle: There is more than one solution. `self` isn't applicable in your case. Please read the whole answer. Make sure you understand how `this` behaves.