# Discord.js: How to check something at all times?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I basically want to run something at all times. I need it to run at least once a minute. I know how to run something whenever a message is sent. This is my method:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const bot = new Discord.Client();
bot.on('message', message => {
    //code here
});
```

How would I go about running a block of code at least once every minute?

Comment: use setInterval() function.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript: get code to run every minute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13304471/javascript-get-code-to-run-every-minute)

Comment: Or these ones - https://stackoverflow.com/q/3138756/3966682, https://stackoverflow.com/q/7188145/3966682

Answer (score 1):

you can create a function and use `bot.setInterval()` to run it every x amounts of milliseconds, it's best you initialise it in the `ready` event.

```js
const doSomething = () => {
  // Do something
}

bot.on('ready', () => {
  bot.setInterval(doSomething(), 5000) // Runs every 5 seconds
})
```

Comment: thank you! I will try that, and if it doesn't work (which I really doubt) I will let you know