# React, how to check if state is remaining in certain value for certain time?

Tags: reactjs, state, debouncing

I have a state value, it may change from time to time. I want to have a flag that indicate "this state has been staying in value x without any changes for y amount of time"

How do I achieve this?

P.S, if you played Oxygen Not Included, this is the logic I want: https://oxygennotincluded.fandom.com/wiki/FILTER_Gate

Update: can't use setInterval/polling for this.

Comment: What is the reason you cannot use setInterval?
Is using [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout) an option? (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7188188/12559207) for an example of how to use it)

Comment: @Soenderby setInterval + polling can't give me fine control of the exact time window. setTimeout is ok, but one setTimeout can't fulfill requirement. e.g when value is not in target value during the setTimeout, the flag shouldn't get triggered.

Comment: I have posted an answer with a suggestion. I am curious as to what you are using this component for that requires that fine control of the time. Are you making a game of your own?

Answer (score 0):

The code in this answer is available at
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-qjmyix?file=src%2FApp.js

The function `useStateWithTimeFlag` in the snippet below, returns an object with functions identical to those of `setState`, as well as a function for getting the elapsed time, and a variable with the elapsed time.
You can use whichever you prefer.

```
import React, { useState, useRef, useEffect, useCallback } from 'react';

const useStateWithTimeFlag = (initValue) => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(initValue);
  const [ElapsedTime, setElapsedTime] = useState(0);
  const timeRef = useRef(new Date());

  const getTime = useCallback(() => {
    return (new Date() - timeRef.current) / 1000;
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    const i = setInterval(() => {
      setElapsedTime(getTime());
    }, 1000);
    return () => {
      clearInterval(i);
    };
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    timeRef.current = new Date();
  }, [value]);

  return {
    value,
    setValue,
    getTime,
    ElapsedTime,
  };
};
```

The first `useEffect` hook updates the `ElapsedTime` variable once every second.
The second hook resets the timer, whenever the state changes.

This components shows how the function can be used.

```
export default function App() {
  const { setValue, value, ElapsedTime, getTime } = useStateWithTimeFlag('');

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello StackBlitz!</h1>
      <div>
        {' '}
        value: {value} stay there in {ElapsedTime} second{' '}
      </div>
      <div>
        {' '}
        value: {value} stay there in {getTime()} second{' '}
      </div>
      <input value={value} onChange={(e) => setValue(e.target.value)} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: sorry, one requirement, can you do it without setInternal?

Answer (score 0):

In the following snippet I have adapted the answer given by @WestMountain to more closely imitate the functionality of the filter gate described in your link.

This component will only change the exposed value after it has remained unchanged for the amount of time specified by the `delay` parameter.

```
import React, { useState, useRef, useEffect, useCallback } from 'react';

const useStateWithTimeFlag = (initValue, delay) => {
  const [internalValue, setInternalValue] = useState(initValue);
  const [ElapsedTime, setElapsedTime] = useState(0);
  const timeRef = useRef(new Date());
  const timeoutRef = useRef(null);

  const getTime = useCallback(() => {
    return (new Date() - timeRef.current) / 1000;
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    const i = setInterval(() => {
      setElapsedTime(getTime());
    }, 10);
    return () => {
      clearInterval(i);
    };
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    // Reset timer when internalValue changes
    timeRef.current = new Date();
  }, [internalValue]);

  const setValue = (value) => {
    // Remove any existing timeout
    if (timeoutRef.current !== null) 
      clearTimeout(timeoutRef.current)
    // Create new timeout that will set internalValue after delay has expired
    timeout = setTimeout(function() { setInternalValue(value) }, delay);
    timeoutRef.current = timeout
  }  
  return {
    internalValue,
    setValue,
    getTime,
    ElapsedTime,
  };
};
```

The function to set `internalValue` is not exposed. It has been replaced with the function `setValue` that only sets the internal value after a delay has expired. If the value is changed again (by another call to `setValue`) before the delay has passed, the timeout is reset.

With regards to polling, I am not sure there is a good way to get around it. I do not know the context of your application, but I would suggest simply lowering the delay in setInterval.
In the snippet I have set it to 10 milliseconds which is 100 updates per second. (Note: This may impact performance)

Another option is that you could make it event based.