# Webpage that displays the result of a function run every x seconds

Tags: python, web, bottle

I want a small web page, that once every x seconds, runs a function.(It will display the result of that function)

```
import datetime
from bottle import Bottle, run

app = Bottle()

@app.route('/')
def hello():
    return datetime.datetime.now()

run(app, host='localhost', port=8080, reloader=True, interval=5)
```

Right now I've got this. I'm using pythonanywhere for hosting and this won't even run. Error logs state:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/local/bin/uwsgi'
```

I'm kind lost on this one...

Comment: PythonAnywhere dev here.  The call to `run` won't work on PythonAnywhere -- it uses uWSGI to host web apps, which runs them inside one or more separate processes.  That's how it scales up -- when you get a more expensive hosting plan, it starts up more processes so that you can handle extra traffic.  Perhaps you could give more detail about what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Yep, sure. I have a function that runs every x seconds. I want to display for example one.html page if that function returns true, else i want to display two.html.

Comment: What does the function do?  Where should it run?

Comment: It checks an api. It returns true or false depending on a certain value. Where should it run? I don't get it, sorry.

Comment: I guess I'm just confused about the larger issue of what you're trying to achieve.  If it's a web app, couldn't you just hit the API on every hit?  If you're trying to avoid hammering the API with too many hits, then perhaps you could cache the result?

Answer (score 0):

not sure exactly what you are doing, but i think you might have more luck if you do this on the browser side instead of the server side.

for example, look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2170923/whats-the-easiest-way-to-call-a-function-every-5-seconds-in-jquery)