# how to click a button automatically for every 10ms?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to scripting and i'm want to create a script so that it automatically clicks an "Add to Cart" button on the webpage once I visit it

**HTML CODE IN THE BUTTON IS**

```
<div id="gb_atc_e0c344b8" class="a-section a-spacing-small a-visible">
<div class="a-button-stack">
<span class="a-button a-spacing-none a-button-primary a-button-icon" id="a-autoid-0">
<span class="a-button-inner">
<i class="a-icon a-icon-cart"/>
<button title="Add to Shopping Cart" class="a-button-text a-text-null" type="button" id="a-autoid-0-announce">Add to Cart</button>
</span>
</span>
</div>
</div>
```

I've tried using the following script but none of them working
If someone could help me create a script that would automatically click the add to cart button I would be extremely grateful

---

```
setInterval(function() {
    $('.a-text-null').trigger('click');
}, 10);
```

---

```
setInterval(function() {
   $("#a-autoid-0-announce").trigger('click');
}, 10);
```

---

```
setInterval(function() {
     $('.a-text-null').trigger('click');
}, 10);
```

---

```
setInterval(function() {
     $("#a-autoid-0-announce").trigger('click');
}, 10);
```

---

Comment: is not `click()` function working?

Comment: Why the hell would you want to click that button every 10ms?

Comment: Where is the function for the button itself?

Comment: @Sirko To boost sell rating, i guess...

Comment: Seriously, this is obviously a XY problem. Ask specific question regarding your former issue, not the fix you think would work

Comment: How exactly have you confirmed that none of these approaches are "working"?  When you debug this, does the code execute at all?  Does it repeat at the desired interval?  Does the jQuery selector find the element(s) you're looking for?  Is there even a click handler to be invoked?

Comment: no it is for ordering product in a flash sale as it lasts only for 2 to 3 seconds

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the easiest way to call a function every 5 seconds in jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2170923/whats-the-easiest-way-to-call-a-function-every-5-seconds-in-jquery)

Comment: Your code look right but there is no click callback. I have check it in this bin
http://jsbin.com/xeyapayale/1/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: @David Any one of the code is not hitting the Add to cart button

Comment: try on this website i'm this as reference    http://www.amazon.in/dp/B00NTYJQM2/ref=gb1h_img_m-2_3007_b78bdf33?smid=A14UQ4H17XUX90&pf_rd_m=A1VBAL9TL5WCBF&pf_rd_t=101&pf_rd_s=merchandised-search-2&pf_rd_r=19DPX3D3MYEYNA0EAF3D&pf_rd_i=4192584031&pf_rd_p=578443007

Comment: @Chaitanya: Did *you* try on that website?  Because when I try I get a *very specific* error message.  `"$ is not a function"`  You need to load the jQuery library before you can use it.

Comment: @David is their any other way to add to cart button without jQuery libraries

Comment: @Chaitanya: Sure, you can trigger the click event.  For example, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2381572/how-can-i-trigger-a-javascript-event-click

Comment: @David As i'm new to coding i'm struggling to find solution for 5 hours. Ur help made me to solve within 5 minute Thank u very much

Answer (score 0):

```
window.setInterval(function(){
  $("#a-autoid-0-announce").trigger('click');
}, 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

As we can't see the complete code, make sure that you have attached event handlers to the elements as well, e.g.

```
$("a-autoid-0-announce").on("click", function(){
        // do something
});
```

Comment: Here is the reference i'm using this page HTML code http://www.amazon.in/dp/B00NTYJQM2/ref=gb1h_img_m-2_3007_b78bdf33?smid=A14UQ4H17XUX90&pf_rd_m=A1VBAL9TL5WCBF&pf_rd_t=101&pf_rd_s=merchandised-search-2&pf_rd_r=19DPX3D3MYEYNA0EAF3D&pf_rd_i=4192584031&pf_rd_p=578443007