# How to show and then hide elements with setTimeout or setInterval and JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I tried the following codes (with my own functionality)

```
(function (){ 
  $(".video-front").show(); 
  setTimeout(arguments.callee, 10000); 
})();
```

form this post [Calling a function every 60 seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3138756/calling-a-function-every-60-seconds)

and

```
setInterval(function(){ 
  $(".video-AdClick-front").show(); 
}, 10000);
```

from this post [What's the easiest way to call a function every 5 seconds in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2170923/whats-the-easiest-way-to-call-a-function-every-5-seconds-in-jquery)

but still is not working, example i want to call function every 5 sec, when i add those codes that call function only one time after 5 sec do not call function every 5 sec?

Comment: Please include the actual code you're using that is not working.

Comment: Your code works fine. Can you clarify what you mean by it isn't working?

Comment: yes the code is corect, in my script is not working, my question is what a problem may be, who performs the function only once?

Comment: *"Yes, this code works, but I have a different code that doesn't work. Why does MY other code not work?"* @Luan, Seriously? If you want us to tell you why your code doesn't work, you need to post the code that doesn't work; not the one that works.

Comment: honestly I do not know, but i know the code from Mr. Scott Marcus is working, but i don't say those codes are not corect i say those codes are not working with me and i don't know why, but now im happy i have fix that problem. Thank you all, Respect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your timers will work just fine with either of those examples.

But, based on your comment below, it appears that both of your timer functions call the `.show()` method, which makes them visible. When the next timer runs, it will just show what's already being shown. That's why it appears to you that it's not working. It is working, but there's nothing new to see after the functions run the first time. What are you trying to accomplish? A show/hide situation? If that is the case, don't use `.show()`, use `.toggle()`.

```js
(function (){
    $("#one").toggle("slow");
    setTimeout(arguments.callee, 1000);
})();

setInterval(function(){
    $("#two").toggle("slow");
}, 1000);
```

```css
#one, #two { float:left; width:40%; } /* Just for fun! */
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="one">Message one</div>
<div id="two">Message two</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help I have add this code like this     `(function (){
    $(".video-front").show();
    setTimeout(arguments.callee, 10000);
})();`

`setInterval(function(){
  $(".video-AdClick-front").show();
}, 10000);`  but still is not working is it shows only one time, your code is corect, i don't understand what the problem

Comment: @Luan As you can see, the timers work just fine. If you are experiencing a problem it must be with the code *inside* your timer callback functions. You need to post that code and all code relevant to it.

Comment: Yes This is Working :) Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Luan Please edit your question to include the code you added in the comment, as I asked you to do in my comment to your question.

Comment: Mr.Scott Marcus Have edit it now so my probelm is solved, but Thanks for your help MR.@MikeMcCaughan Really Thank You.