# Send API call, observe a specific value, and call again if value changes

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs

I have a function that call a client and get data back and returns it:

```
       const remoteConnection = await
          this.client.connectionStatus(chassi, number, language) || [];
        return {
          data: remoteConnection as RemoteInfo,
          read: new Date()
        };
```

The response will be in this form:

```
 {
   connectionStatus: "",
   online: ""
 }
```

connectionStatus can have three states:

```
'disconnected'
'pending'
'connected'
```

I want to call my API and send the data. IF 'connectionStatus' is 'pending', I want to call the API every 5s to check if it changes to 'connected'. In that case, I want to return the data again with the new values.

In a nutshell:

Make API call and return the data.
If 'connectionStatus' in the return data is equal to 'pending', make a new call every 5s to check if 'connectionStatus' is equal to 'connected'. If true, return data again.

How to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `timer` to trigger making your api call and use `takeUntil` to stop whenever the status meets your condition:

```js
const data$ = timer(0, 5000).pipe(
  concatMap(() => client.connectionStatus()),
  takeWhile(resp => resp.connectionStatus === 'pending', true),
  map(data => ({ data, read: new Date() }))
);
```

Here's the flow:

- [`timer`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/creation/timer) emits immediately, then every 5 seconds
- [`concatMap`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/concatmap) calls your method and emits the result of the promise
- [`takeWhile`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/filtering/takewhile) causes the stream to complete when the condition is met
- [`map`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/map) simply transforms the `RemoteInfo` response to your desired shape

Simply subscribe to this observable to trigger execution and receive emissions:

```js
data$.subscribe();
```

Here's a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-67263922?file=index.ts&devtoolsheight=100) sample.

If the observable will have multiple subscribers, you may wish to prevent multiple separate calls to your api by leveraging the [`share`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/multicasting/share) operator, which will cause all subscribers to share the same subscription:

```js
const data$ = timer(0, 5000).pipe(
  concatMap(() => client.connectionStatus()),
  takeWhile(resp => resp.connectionStatus === 'pending', true),
  map(data => ({ data, read: new Date() })),
  share() // <---
);
```

Answer (score 1):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2170923/whats-the-easiest-way-to-call-a-function-every-5-seconds-in-jquery) shows how to run a function every 5 seconds:

> var intervalId = window.setInterval(function(){
> /// call your function here
> }, 5000);

In this case, you would run this function while connectionStatus = pending

```
var intervalId = window.setInterval(function() {
  if (connectionStatus != pending) {
    clearInterval(intervalId); // stop the loop
    return data;
  } 
}, 5000);
```